# On hover for each <span> tag that is a descendent of <h1>, set background-color to blue and color to white

Tags: html, css

On hover for each `<span>` tag that is a descendent of `<h1>`, set `background-color` to `blue` and `color` to `white`. I tried `:hover h1 span` but it still shows an error.

```
{
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please include an [MCVE], include relevant HTML and CSS including selectors. What errors? CSS does not throw errors. You've tagged this with `javascript` but have no javascript code, where does javascript come into this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for this:

```css
h1 > span:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

Where `>` reference a direct child. [MDN "Child combinator"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1>span:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><span>Hello</span></h1>
  <h1><span>Hello</span></h1>
  <h1><span>Hello</span></h1>
  <h2><span>HI</span></h2>
</body>

</html>
```